# What is wrong with the code? It is not getting out of the loop

Tags: c, file-io

Question scenario: There are 2 files `customer.dat` and `transaction.dat` containing number of records (record structure is in code defined bt structures) .In transacton.dat file there are 2 tran_types(d/c debit or credit) as per  debit and credit the balance in customer.dat file will be updated .

```c
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    struct tran
    {
        int accno;
        char tran_type;
        float amount;
    };
    struct tran t;
    struct cust
    {
        int accno;
        char name[30];
        float balance;
    };
    struct cust c;
    FILE *fp,*ft;
    fp=fopen("customer.dat","rb+");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cant open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    ft=fopen("transaction.dat","rb");
    if(ft == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    while(fread(&c,sizeof(c),1,fp)==1)
    {
        
        rewind(ft);
        while(fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,ft)==1)
        {
            if(c.accno == t.accno)
            {
                if(t.tran_type=='d')
                {
                    c.balance=(c.balance-t.amount);
                    fseek(fp,-sizeof(c),SEEK_CUR);
                    fwrite(&c,sizeof(c),1,fp);
                    
                    
                }
                else if(t.tran_type =='c')
                {
                    
                    c.balance= (c.balance + t.amount);
                    fseek(fp,-sizeof(c),SEEK_CUR);
                    fwrite(&c,sizeof(c),1,fp);
                
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
    printf("Success");
}
```

Comment: What do you think the rewind(ft) function call does?

Comment: Each iteration of the outer loop calls `rewind` on the file used by the inner loop.  Meanwhile the inner loop can call `fseek` to move the seek position backward on the file used by the outer loop.  It is not surprising if this loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with your code. But there are two problems:

1. You are using a `printf()` without a line feed `\n` in the end of the
   format string. That way, the stream is not flushed to stdout and
   would take many prints to go to the output, or only when the program
   ended.
2. You have used a 5 second `sleep()`. Depending on the number of
   customers and transactions, your loop might last a very long time.

Those two facts together imply that you probably have not waited enough time to receive the result. Just remove the `sleep()` and it will become fast and work properly.

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit code before posting.. I was using sleep function to stop the screen and know whats actually going (as a debugging purpose). I have edited the code now

Comment: I have run the original code here without the sleep() call and had no problems.